# ms access 2007 simple select query wizard, the available fields box is empty

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am trying to make a simple select query based on a cross tab query. If I use the query wizard the available fields box is empty and I cannot select any fields. I then tried to make the query manualy: in design view I select the fields to be shown, but when I try to run the query (or see it in datasheet view) I got the error: "Too few parameters. Expected 2. (Error 3061)"

Am I missing something, can you please help me
thank you in advance

Comment: When I make a crosstab query it has 6 columns, but then when I try to make a select query based on this query in the firs popup window of the wizard the available fields box is empty and I cannot procede... What could be the problem?

Comment: In the crosstab query in design view I enter in the Column Headings property the names of the two columns that I want to have in the select query, and then there are fields to select in the select query wizard, but when I create the select query I cannot run it and I got a popup window "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables. (Error 3071)"--- what could be the problem?

Comment: Generally, I try to make the user able to enter arbitrary start_date and end_date in two textboxes in the form, which I then use as date criteria in the first query (e.g if the user enters the start_date 1/1/2014 and end_date 10/1/2014 the query outputs only the records that falls within those two dates). The question is: is it possible to do it in Access 2007 like I wrote? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance